# How do I input custom names into my game?

Tags: prison-architect

I am trying to get custom names in the game for Prison Architect but it wont let me because I already own the game, and it comes with the game. How do I get custom names into the game?

Comment: I don't know anything about Prison Architect but after about 10 seconds of googling: http://support.introversion.co.uk/customer/portal/articles/1007776-name-in-the-game

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a forum account to sign in. Go to http://forums.introversion.co.uk/index.php and follow the instructions to create and activate an account.

Once you have an account, go to http://www.prison-architect.com/developer/nameingame/

If you bought your game from Steam or from a Humble Bundle, you will need the product key you received when you bought it. If you bought the game directly from Introvision, you will need the email you used.